# plot: y axis as factor in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm struggling with a plot. I have a vector "a":

```
   h1    h2    h3    h4 
1.000 0.880 0.746 0.761
```

These are data of normalized concentration of an element in a soil profile.

I would like to have on the `x` axis the concentration `(1, 0.880, 0.746, 0.761)` and on the `y` axis the different horizons `(h1, h2, h3, h4)`. But I would like the `y` axis to go downward (as in a soil profile), and the `x` axis on the top of that plot.

Here's what I've got so far: (I have tried many other things but without success)

```
test=factor(names(a))
plot(a,test)
axis(3)
```

This shouldn't be so hard but even after checking `?axis`, `?plot` and `?par`, I can't manage to get what I want.

Comment: please include at least 10 items of the vector, also clarify what do you mean by `i would like the y axis to go downward`

Comment: I think he means the x is across the top and the y drops down from there like going down into the ground)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that, you may want to customize your plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(horizon = c("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"), vals = c(1.000, 0.880, 0.746, 0.761))
ggplot(a, aes(x = vals, y = horizon)) +
  geom_point() +  
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(a$horizon)))+
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top")
```

The `ggplot2` package is far easier to customize.

Comment: ok, this is a nice way to go, 

but in this solution, the value do not correspond to the correct horizon anymore. h1=0.761, h2=0.746, h3=0.88, h4=1.